# Install tkinter on Python3 ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter

I am installing tkinter on python3 by running:
`$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

This returns (translated): `$ python3-tk is already in its latest version (3.6.9-1~18.04)`

However, when I run:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

I get the following error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk'

Comment: Are you sure you are using python3?

Comment: Yes, I'm using python3 for sure.

Comment: Before you import ttk, you have to import tkinter

Comment: Try opening a python3 shell by typing `python3`. Then type `import tkinter`. What happens? I am just trying to isolate your problem.

Comment: When I type import tkinter in blows up with the same error message. (ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk')

Comment: Try using "Option 2" in the [following documentation](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installlinux)

Comment: How are you running this statement? From an interactive prompt, or in a file? If in a file, did you name your file `tkinter.py`?

Comment: @Bryan: From the error message, `ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk'` it looks like the attempt to execute statement was by a Python interpreter.

Comment: @martineau: yes, of course it was by a python interpreter. However, if they named their own file `tkinter.py`, this is exactly the sort of error I would expect.

Comment: Either in the command line either in a file it doesn't work

Comment: what happens when you do `import tkinter`? Either you will get an error (but not the exact same error) or it will succeed. If it succeeds, what do you get when you next do `print(tkinter.__file__)`?

Comment: @BryanOakley He said "When I type import tkinter in blows up with the same error message. (ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk')". Why would he get the error for 'ttk' when importing 'tkinter'?

Comment: @Redline: I don’t think it’s possible. I don’t think that is what actually happened.

Comment: @AjapolloTrukatila You should post the full traceback message for better understanding your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The import should be `import tkinter`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules

Comment: First i type: from tkinter import *. Next from tkinter import ttk.   It works in my windows computer, but not in Ubuntu

Comment: `import tkinter` won't import `ttk`. `from tkinter import ttk` works for fine me (on Windows anyway).

Comment: While it's true that you can import tkinter the way you say, that doesn't answer the question. They are trying to import `ttk`, and the way in which they are doing it is the correct way to import it. In other words, the problem isn't with the import statement.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. So have you got any idea of what may be the problem?

Comment: True, this should work indeed. Could you check that you have the file `ttk.py` in `/usr/lib/python3.*/tkinter` just to verify that it was an issue with the `apt-get install`?